# How to Discern an Asyndetic Coordinate Subject Complement?

Tags: complements

> ". . .to let fall is **absolute indifference, absolute contempt**;"

I think this got maybe discerned an asyndetic coordinate subject complement. May something like *He was a moody man, **his temper was never equable*** seem maybe something like an asyndetic coordinate subject complement?

Comment: This is an advanced question. It will need a real linguist to even understand what you're asking.  Please post it on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.

Comment: *absolute indifference, absolute contempt* is an [asyndetic coordination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton), but the sentence *He was a moody man, his temper was never equable* is an example of [parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis).

Comment: All right. I guess I may do that, Brian Hitchcock. I appreciate it.

Comment: That information on parataxis seems interesting. I thank you, Damkerng T..

Answer (score 4):

> He was a moody man, his temper was never equable.

There are two independent clauses above.  The comma could be replaced with a full stop or a semi-colon.  I would consider the comma merely a vagary of punctuation, and would not process the two sentences as one.

Let's remove the "was":

> He was a moody man, his temper never equable.

There, "his temper never equable" is a supplemental clause.

> He was a moody man, an intemperate man.

Here we have asyndetic coordination.

Comment: I think I may get main clauses, subordinate clauses, adjective clauses and noun clauses. I may not get supplemental clauses. I may not get how that may seem a clause. I guess I thought clauses got to contain a subject and verb. It seems to contain a subject. I may not discern a verb. And so asyndetic coordination seems to mostly contain maybe no and, no verb, and maybe no subject? I thank you, TRomano.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the connecting words "and/or" are lacking between "absolute indifferene" and "absolute contempt" you are right. And, yes, your bold part is a subject complement.